# How to get assembly path from fully qualified name, without loading it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the fully qualified name of an assembly (and/or an AssemblyName object), e.g.

```
System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

These can be names of assemblies that are not currently loaded in the running application

I would like to figure out where this assembly located is located / would be loaded from on the user's machine.

For example, if I tried Assembly.Load() or .ReflectionOnlyLoad() on above string, this would load fine and I could inspect the resultig Assembly object's "Location" property.

However, I would like to get this information without having to actually load (and having to go through the trouble with AppDomains etc. to unload afterwards) the assembly.

So basically, how can I get the file path that Assembly.Load() *would* use to load from (but without me having to actually Load the assembly)?

Thanks!

---

edit: Just some info on why (I think I) need to do this:

I'm creating a C# script editor, in which users should be able to target certain .Net Framework versions, ideally without having the development SDKs installed on their machines (yay, Roslyn!).

So in my editor, I'm including the FrameworkList.xml files for all framework versions, which contain all information to construct the fully qualified assembly names that ship with the given Framework version.

Now in my editor, I am listing all of these. When the user wants to reference them in their project, I need to create a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference in order to pass this reference on to the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project. The only factory method for such a MetadataReference I can use (without loading the assembly) is the one accepting a full physical file path to it. Hence, I'm looking to figure out where the assemblies with the given AssemblyName are located on disk.

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Hmm I hope not, but I will post some additional info what I'm trying to acheive with it in a second

Comment: And what problem exactly you have with ReflectionOnlyLoad?